# I'm at the edge of solving this. just see...anyone can tell me what should I change?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    char name[20];

    printf("Type your name please: ");
    fgets(name,20,stdin);

    switch(name[20])
    {
    case 'name1':
        printf("\nYou are good\n");
        break;
    case 'name2':
        printf("\nYou are not so good\n");
        break;
    case 'name3':
        printf("\nYou are bad\n");
        break;
    case 'name4':
        printf("\nYou are very ba\n");
        break;
    default:
        printf("\nYou entered an invalid letter\n");
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: You forgot to enable your compiler warnings. Do it now and never ever don't do it again in the future.

Comment: Bizarre... I never knew about multi-character constants in C until this morning and now I see this unintentional use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `switch` to compare strings.  It only works on integer types.  Also, string constants are denoted with double quotes (`"`), not single quotes (`'`).  You need to use `strcmp` to compare strings:

```
if (!strcmp(name, "name1")) {
    printf("\nYou are good\n");
} else if (!strcmp(name, "name2")) {
    printf("\nYou are not so good\n");
} else if (!strcmp(name, "name3")) {
    printf("\nYou are bad\n");
} else if (!strcmp(name, "name4")) {
    printf("\nYou are very ba\n");
} else {
    printf("\nYou entered an invalid letter\n");
}
```

Comment: Thnx. BUt still I've got "You entered an invalid letter".

Comment: @AlifRejuanTalukder the man page for `fgets()` will tell you it appends a `newline` to the end of the string, if there was one in the input. You must remove that before comparing the input with your strings.

Answer (score 1):

`switch(expression)`

*The `expression` used in a switch statement must have an integral or enumerated type, or be of a class type in which the class has a single conversion function to an integral or enumerated type.*

You can't use `switch` to compare two strings as *dbush* said.It is better to compare the two strings and print the desired result.

You should also remove the trailing newline character as otherwise you won`t get the desired result:

```
fgets(name,20,stdin);
len = strlen(name);
name[len - 1] = '\0';
```

Comment: Then how I do this. Can you please show me or correct my code? It'll be great help :)

Comment: Go with the code *dbush* just posted. That is the correct way to do it. You may use scanf("%s" name) in palce of fgets.

Comment: @AlifRejuanTalukder Check my edited answer for your problem.